# Printing to a USB printer with Python on a Mac

Tags: macos, printing, usb

I have a Star TSP600 thermal receipt printer attached to my macbook via usb. The drivers are installed, and I can print to it using the normal Mac print dialog.

How I can construct a program to send text to the printer? Is there a guide to basic printing interfaces? I generally work in Python, and I'd be willing to learn another language if it's appropriate for the task. Just looking for the basic "Hello World" example to get off the ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [CUPS command line options](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html).

Then you could use [popen](http://docs.python.org/library/popen2.html) to send text to the printer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import popen2
popen2.popen4("lpr -P [printer] " + output_file)
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is struggling with this, here's the specific command I had to use: /usr/bin/lp -o media=Custom.12x100mm /tmp/label.pdf

Comment: use sequences in popen: popen2.popen2(["lpr", "-P", printermame, filename]); no reason to use popen4 if you don't use stderr, etc.
Nowadays you should use subprocess instead of popen;
You can also use stdin for data: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE; p = Popen([...arguments...], stdin=PIPE); p.stdin.write(filedata); p.communicate()

Comment: @Bemmu Thank you soo much for ur comment ! Saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in MacOS Ventura (13.2.1) and Python 3.9, with a USB printer, but using Wi-Fi (printer plugged into my router) --

```
import os

printer = os.popen('lpr', 'w')
printer.write('This is a test.\n')
printer.close()
```

The above prints to the default printer. If you wish to print to another on your network, use this in `Terminal` to find the printer name:

`lpstat -p`

Then, change the `printer =` line to specify the printer name:

`printer = os.popen('lpr -P <printer_name>', 'w')`

eg,

`printer = os.popen('lpr -P Canon_iP110_series', 'w')`

---

Attribution to [this really old thread at Bytes.com (from 2005!)](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/169648-print-printer)